# I get 'out of stack space' with crystl32.ocx / vbasic 5 when I run the report twice

Tags: crystal-reports, stack-overflow

The first several times I run the report it prints OK but when I try to UnLoad the form that's running it I get 'Out of Stack Space' error 28 and the program terminates with that error.

The details point to to  crystl32.ocx version 4.6.1.0 as the problem.

How can I release stack space when the report is closed???????

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with that version of the Crystal Report control, but does the control have a `Reset()` method?  Without resetting, you're not telling the control to release any resources allocated for the printing of a report.

Answer (score 0):

Well I get this error when  I  Unload the form so everything should be released then.
I have found out that If I only have one form open at a time I do not have this problem.
I guess the reports just use too many resources ....  Would be nice to have 2 reports open though.   I can run the same report many times and keep them open but not 2 different reports

Comment: Are you using two `crystl32.ocx` controls, or using the same control to open two windows?